# Help me undo gas stove flex connection

Tags: gas, stove

I am trying to unhook a gas stove flex line. The joint B turns fine so I can unthread it. However the joint A seems to be seized and won’t turn. As a result, I cannot remove the hose as the hose cools on itself. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to loosen this joint so that the connection turns freely at the flex line and doesn’t twist when I turn the nut? Thanks.

EDIT: To aid others who had trouble removing this, added photo to show how this was finally undone, with help of this amazing group. Thanks @AlaskaMan. Basically the connection was between two chrome hex parts and it was just too tight. I was afraid to break it but the answers here gave me confidence to just go with it. Make sure you have a couple of good pipe wrenches.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Joint A isn't a joint. Are you referring to the joints _below_ each of those indicators? One is where the white tape is on the iron, and the other is between the two hex sections.

Comment: @isherwood yes, sorry, if this was asked confusingly. I meant, shouldn’t the section between A and B be spinning freely to allow flex line stay static? It is not spinning between the two chrome hex sections at all.

Comment: A is the fitting on the yellow gas line, B is the nipple on the black pipe. The two are made to go together, it is a flared compression fitting and does not  flex. a wrench on B  holds it from moving will a wrench on A turns A counterclockwise.

Comment: And being a flared connection it does not get pipe dope when you reinstall it.

Comment: @alaskaMan thanks, this worked. It seems that it was just tight. I was afraid to break what seemed like 1 piece. If you would like to write your comment as an answer, I’d happily upvote it. Thanks everyone who helped. I will post an “after” photo to hopefully help other to see it  undone.

Comment: @David since it seems Alaska Man's answer solved your problem, you can also click the checkmark below the voting arrow to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @PhilippNagel Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A is the fitting on the yellow gas line,

B is the nipple on the black pipe.

The two are made to go together, it is a flared compression fitting and does not flex.

[Threaded joints explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIEBZ1V9jH0).

[How to wrap PTFE tape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8NvdluoE-0).

a wrench on the nipple (B) holds it from moving while a wrench on fitting (A) turns the fitting counterclockwise. Being a flared connection it **does not get pipe dope** when you reinstall it.

Since you have loosened B you will need to reset it. It **does** get pipe dope or PTFE  tape (Teflon) made for gas.  It appears white water Teflon tape was used.

After you get  A and B apart, take B off of the black pipe and thoroughly clean off the threads, apply [PTFE tape for gas](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004MYFPAK) connections OR pipe dope (***not both***) and reset B onto the black pipe. It will be helpful to have a [PIPE wrench](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Kobalt-14-in-Cast-Iron-Pipe-Wrench/50069711) on the black pipe while you tighten the B nipple down. [How to use a pipe wrench](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXXlpvQ2R8c).